# Can I use TOR browser without using TOR network?

Tags: browser, proxy, privacy, tor

The TOR browser is a nice browser even without TOR. Using full on TOR seems a bit extreme to me and is beyond my patience, on the other hand, using a normal Firefox feels like yelling my canvas fingerprints all over the internet. Can I configure the TOR browser to **not** go through the TOR network?

Comment: `TOR_SKIP_LAUNCH=1 ./start-tor-browser.desktop` starts the web browser without connecting to Tor. You will then need to adjust the web browser's netowrk proxy settings so that it connects to the internet without a proxy (i.e. Tor).

Comment: @Flux `TOR_TRANSPROXY=1` might also be necessary now, as of Tor Browser 9.0, see this page: https://www.ghacks.net/2018/11/26/can-you-use-the-tor-browser-without-tor-connection/#comment-4443139

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Upper right hand side of Tor Browser click on the three horizontal bars, click on Options, select the Advanced tab, click on Network, click on Settings, select "No Proxy" and hit OK.

Then type "about:config" into the url bar, go to "network.proxy.socks_remote_dns" right click and select Toggle.

At that point your browser won´t be using TOR proxy to access to the internet, but if you also want to disable the TOR service running in the background type "about:config" into the url bar, go to "extensions.torlauncher.start_tor", right click and select Toggle

Hope i`ve helped you :)

Comment: Additionally, to prevent the above settings from being restored to the default Tor browsing mode when restarting the browser, you need to disable the extensions `Torbutton` and `TorLauncher`.

Comment: Does this still work? I changed "about:config" in options but when I choose "No Proxy" in settings, the browser doesn't work [screenshot](https://imgur.com/FkenEiu)

Comment: The process to do this is different now as of Tor Browser 9.0, see this blog post: https://www.ghacks.net/2018/11/26/can-you-use-the-tor-browser-without-tor-connection/#comment-4443139

Answer (score 4):

Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Tor Browser 12.0.6 (based on Mozilla Firefox 102.11.0esr) (64-bit)

In **about:config** set

```
extensions.torbutton.test_enabled = false
extensions.torlauncher.start_tor = false
network.dns.disabled = false
network.proxy.type = 0
```

Use of shell variables is not required

Comment: This is working for macOS Monterey 12.5.1  too, thanks ;)