# Can I use TOR browser without using TOR network? UPDATED for 2018

Tags: browser, proxy, privacy, tor

This question was asked 2 years ago and answered successfully back then ([Can I use TOR browser without using TOR network?](https://superuser.com/questions/1117383/can-i-use-tor-browser-without-using-tor-network)), but the Tor Browser has changed since then and these old instructions are no longer fully sufficient for the current release of TB.  The problem is that TB resets a few of these modified settings each time it starts so that you have to re-enter these settings over and over.   It does work once you make these manual changes, but they are lost on re-start.  Any solutions to make these settings permanent or otherwise achieve using the TB without the Tor network?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Which settings? If you are specific about what works and what doesn't it's easier to answer :)

Comment: *"The problem is that TB resets a few of these modified settings each time it starts..."* - You did not list or detail the settings which are causing the problems. I think it makes it more difficult to provide suggestions and answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use TOR browser without using TOR network?](https://superuser.com/questions/1117383/can-i-use-tor-browser-without-using-tor-network)

Answer (score 2):

I shameless copied this Answer from [this](https://superuser.com/a/1117660) answer and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1117383/can-i-use-tor-browser-without-using-tor-network#comment1810693_1117660) comment, because I just tested it and it works perfectly.

- Go to *Tor Browser* → <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> → *Options* → Scroll to the bottom and under "Network Proxy" select *Settings* → *"No Proxy"*.
- Go to *about:config* in address bar → search for `network.proxy.socks_remote_dns` → set value to *false* (by double clicking) → search for `extensions.torlauncher.start_tor` → set value to *false* (by double clicking).
- Go to *about:addons* in address bar → disable *Torbutton* and *TorLauncher* by clicking on the *Disable* button.

Changes will persist during restarts.

Other options are: install Firefox and the addons *HTTPS Everywhere* and *NoScript* or *uMatrix*. Go to *about:preferences#privacy* in the address bar and under *Cookies and Site Data* select *Keep until: Firefox is closed* and *Accept Cookies: Never*.

Comment: This seems to solve the problem.  I guess should read the entire original posting including the comments.  Sorry but I am unable to mark your solution as correct given my newbie status.

Comment: @Rumboogy You should always be able to mark answers to your own questions as accepted. Are you not seeing the grey checkmark underneath the up/downvote buttons?